# outline of two intersecting circles

Tags: geometry, matlab

What is the best way, elegant in Matlab programming, to find the outline boundary, i.e. the `[x,y]` coordinate, of the three intersecting circles as shown below?

do you have an example of a matlab code to solve this problem?

the plot is generated using the following codes,

`R = 1;
r = 0.5;
m = 37;
for ii=1:m
    theta(ii) = (2*pi/m)*ii;
end
X = R.*cos(theta);
Y = R.*sin(theta);
x1 = R + r.*cos(theta);
y1 = r.*sin(theta);
x2 = -R - r.*cos(theta);
y2 = r.*sin(theta);
x3 = r.*cos(theta);
y3 = R+ r.*sin(theta);`

[image]

Comment: It is not clear to me what you mean by the "boundary".

Comment: I mean the external outline circumference of all the curves (circles)

Answer (score 0):

The figure has reflective symmetry across the $x-$axis, the $y-$axis and the line $x = y$  We can analyze $\frac 18$ the region and multiply.

the circle $x^2 + y^2 =1$ intesects the circle $(x-1)^2 + y^2 = \frac 14$

$x^2 + y^2 = 1\\
x^2 + y^2 - 2x + 1 = \frac 14\\
2x = \frac 74\\
x = \frac 78\\
y = \sqrt {1-(\frac 78)^2}$

The partial circumference of the small circle is from the x-axis to the point of intersection:

$\frac 12 \arccos -\frac 14$

The partial circumference of the large cirlce from the point of intesection to the line $x= y$:

$\frac \pi4 - \arccos \frac 78$

$2\pi - 8\arccos \frac 78 + 4\arccos -\frac 14$